# is it possible to add a template to the getter/setter of a data class?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

for example , I want to change all setters this way:

```
this.a = StringUtils.trim(a);
```

If it's a java bean, I can do this by modifying the code generating template of the ide. But Intellij seems not support to atomically add getter/setter for kotlin data class.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: IMHO kotlin data classes can't have custom setter/getters, unless it's not declared in the primary constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to do this as of Kotlin 1.1.

A Kotlin [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html), for the most part, is a class "to do nothing but hold data".

I think the closest you can get is to validate your data upon class initialization and make your data class properties read-only values. e.g.:

```
data class Data(val a: String) {
    init {
        require(a == a.trim())
    }
}
```

The following won't throw an exception:

```
val a = Data("ab")
val b = a.copy(a = "abc")
```

While the following will:

```
val c = a.copy(a = "abc ")
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you declare the property as private, you can create your own getter/setters for accessing it. This example works for me.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var t = test("foo")
    t.setHello("bar")
    println(t)

}

data class test(private var hello: String) {
    fun setHello(blah: String) {
        this.hello = blah
    }
}
```

But you will still have an issue when the property is passed in to the constructor. You will probably need to rethink how you are doing this, either declaring the field private and trimming it in the getter, or not using a data class for this instance.